# Creating Admin Workstation

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-anthos

I am creating an admin workstation on RHEL VM. While running the admin-ws-config.yaml file by using the command - `./gkeadm create admin-workstation [--auto-create-service-accounts]`
, it throws error at Validation category: vCenter
`Credentials: Failed to login. Check credentials or network settings`.
I have attached the screenshot of the error and code also for any reference.

```
gcp:
  # Path of the component access service account's JSON key file
  componentAccessServiceAccountKeyPath: "/root/component-access-key.json"
# Specify which vCenter resources to use
vCenter:
  # The credentials and address GKE On-Prem should use to connect to vCenter
  credentials:
    address: https://10.31.4.95/
    username: "administrator@vsphere.local"
    password: "Password@123"
  datacenter: "Google Anthos - Implementation"
  datastore: "MLOPS"
  cluster: "Anthos-cluster"
  network: "LabNetwork"
  # vSphere vm folder to deploy vms into. defaults to datacenter top level folder
  folder: "vCLS"
  resourcePool: "Anthos-cluster/Resources"
  # Provide the path to vCenter CA certificate pub key for SSL verification
  caCertPath: "/root/vcenter.pem"

# The URL of the proxy for the jump host
proxyUrl: ""
adminWorkstation:
  name: "gke-admin-ws-221111-164725"
  cpus: 4
  memoryMB: 8192
  # The boot disk size of the admin workstation in GB. It is recommended to use a
  # disk with at least 100 GB to host images decompressed from the bundle.
  diskGB: 100
  # Name for the persistent disk to be mounted to the home directory (ending in .vmdk).
  # Any directory in the supplied path must be created before deployment.
  dataDiskName: gke-on-prem-admin-workstation-data-disk/gke-admin-ws-221111-164725-data-disk.vmdk
  # The size of the data disk in MB.
  dataDiskMB: 512
  network:
    # The IP allocation mode: 'dhcp' or 'static'
    ipAllocationMode: "static"
    # The host config in static IP mode. Do not include if using DHCP
    hostConfig:
      # The IPv4 static IP address for the admin workstation
      ip: "10.54.122.96"
      # The IP address of the default gateway of the subnet in which the admin workstation is to be created
      gateway: "10.54.127.254"
      # The subnet mask of the network where you want to create your admin workstation
      # (e.g. 255.255.255.0)
      netmask: "255.255.248.0"
      # The list of DNS nameservers to be used by the admin workstation
      dns:
      - "10.154.248.9"
      - "10.154.248.10"
  # The URL of the proxy for the admin workstation
  proxyUrl: ""
  ntpServer: "10.255.255.240"
```

I'm able to login to vSphere client on browser. What is the underlying issue in this case?